# Magnet pattern and anonmyous functions: Missing parameter type error

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm using the magnet pattern to call the right overloaded method (`flatMap`) depending on whether some implicit parameters exist.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pYQG0Q6TTWuvbjatD7SIxw

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Tester {
  final case class Foo[A](value: A) {
    def flatMap[B](cat: Cat[A, B]): Foo[B] = {
      println("cat")
      cat.f(value)
    }

    def flatMap[B](monkey: Monkey[A, B]): Foo[B] = {
      println("monkey")
      monkey.f(value)
    }

    def map[B](f: A => B): Foo[B] = {
      Foo(f(value))
    }
  }

  case class Banana()
  class Monkey[A, B](val f: A => Foo[B])

  object Monkey {
    implicit def funcToMonkey[A, B](f: A => Foo[B])(implicit i: Banana): Monkey[A, B] = new Monkey(f)
  }
  case class Catnip()
  class Cat[A, B](val f: A => Foo[B])

  object Cat {
    implicit def funcToCat[A, B](f: A => Foo[B])(implicit i: Catnip): Cat[A, B] = new Cat(f)
  }

}

object Main {
  import Tester._
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    for {
      _ <- Foo(1)
      _ <- Foo("asdf")
    } yield ()
  }
}
```

However I'm getting the error `missing parameter type for expanded function`.
If I desugar it to direct flatMap calls I get a similar error:

```
Foo(1).flatMap(_ => Foo("asdf").map(_ => ()))
```

`missing parameter type`

I can solve the problem by explicitly specifying the type of the flatMap parameter (i.e. `.flatMap((_: Int) => ...)`) but I want to avoid that. Even if I do use the parameter, Scala still requires me to specify the type

Is there a way to make the for comprehension code compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can work. To avoid having to provide parameter type for a lambda, the expected type (so `flatMap` parameter's type here) has to be a function type or a SAM type, not just some type which has an implicit conversion from a function type like `Cat` and `Monkey` are.

Before 2.13, you'd also run into a separate problem because the method wasn't allowed to be overloaded, but the fix doesn't cover your situation either:

> [To avoid breaking existing code, we only provide an expected type (for each argument position) when](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6871):
>
> - there is at least one FunctionN type expected by one of the overloads: in this case, the expected
>     type is a FunctionN[Ti, ?], where Ti are the argument types (they must all be =:=), and the expected
>     result type is elided using a wildcard. This does not exclude any overloads that expect a SAM,
>     because they conform to a function type through SAM conversion
> - OR: all overloads expect a SAM type of the same class, but with potentially varying result types
>     (argument types must be =:=)

Neither of these are true for you (`Cat` and `Monkey` are not SAM types and wouldn't work even if they did). I've tried to make `flatMap` take function with implicits directly

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
object Tester {
  final case class Foo[A](value: A) {
    def flatMap[B](f: A => Foo[B])(implicit i: Catnip): Foo[B] = {
      val cat: Cat[A, B] = f
      println("cat")
      cat.f(value)
    }

    def flatMap[B](f: A => Foo[B])(implicit i: Banana): Foo[B] = {
      val monkey: Monkey[A, B] = f
      println("monkey")
      monkey.f(value)
    }

    def map[B](f: A => B): Foo[B] = {
      Foo(f(value))
    }
  }

  case class Banana()
  class Monkey[A, B](val f: A => Foo[B])

  object Monkey {
    implicit def funcToMonkey[A, B](f: A => Foo[B])(implicit i: Banana): Monkey[A, B] = new Monkey(f)
  }
  case class Catnip()
  class Cat[A, B](val f: A => Foo[B])

  object Cat {
    implicit def funcToCat[A, B](f: A => Foo[B])(implicit i: Catnip): Cat[A, B] = new Cat(f)
  }

}

object Main {
  import Tester._
  implicit val cn = Catnip()
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    for {
      _ <- Foo(1)
      _ <- Foo("asdf")
    } yield ()
  }
}
```

but that just gives a different error:

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method flatMap in class Foo of type [B](f: Int => Tester.Foo[B])(implicit i: Tester.Banana)Tester.Foo[B]
and  method flatMap in class Foo of type [B](f: Int => Tester.Foo[B])(implicit i: Tester.Catnip)Tester.Foo[B]
match argument types (Int => Tester.Foo[Unit])
```

Comment: Yes ambiguous overload was why I am exploring magnet pattern in the first place. Seems like I'll need to explore other options. Thanks!